# Запрет неявного преобразования

Tags: c++

```
struct B;
struct A 
{
    operator B();
};
struct B
{
    B operator + (B) {return B();}
};
A::operator B()
{
    return B();
}
int main()
{
    A x;
    B y;
    y+x; // Как запретить неявное преобразование для данного оператора/ группы операторов?
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неявное преобразование можно запретить так:

```
struct A 
{
    explicit operator B();
};
```

Теперь только явно можно преобразовать `A` в `B`

---

Если же хочется оставить неявное преобразование в целом, но в частных случаях оно нежелательно, тогда можно воспользоваться таким трюком:

```
#include <type_traits>
//...
struct B
{
    template<typename TB, typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<TB, B>::value>>
    B operator + (TB) { return B(); }
};
```

Comment: @hero, можно явно приводить тип(`static_cast` или `C-cast`)

Comment: Зачем в первом случае писать `expilicit operator B()`, если можно просто его не писать?

Comment: @hero, если его не писать, то нельзя будет преобрзаовать `A` в `B`, а если сделать `explicit`, то можно будет преобразовать, но только явно(как я уже указал в предыдущем комментарии)

Comment: Теперь ясно, спасибо

Comment: Пишет _[Error] only declarations of constructors can be 'explicit'_

Comment: @hero, значит у Вас старый компилятор

Comment: Если написать в объявлении в классе `explicit`, а в реализации вне класса не писать, то всё норм. Так и должно быть?

Comment: @hero, конечно, я ведь Вам в одном месте указал